# GET-запрос и display:none

Tags: html, display, form, get

Можно сделать так, чтобы при отправке этой формы:

```
<form action="xxx.com" method="get">
    <input name="param_1" type="text" value="string"/>
    <input name="param_2" type="text" style="display:none;" value="string" />
    <input name="param_3" type="text" value="" />
    <input name="param_4" type="text" style="display:none;" value="" />
</form>
```

url выглядел следующим образом:  
xxx.com?param_1=string

т.е. чтобы в GET не передавались те параметры, значения которых не существует или у элемента стоит `"display:none;"`?

Comment: Как инициируется отправка формы? Надо повесить javascript обработчик события, например, `onsubmit` если по нажатию на `submit` происходит отправка, и в этой функции проверить данные и выкинуть ненужные. Вернуть `true`, чтобы отправка данных продолжилась.

Comment: @sergiks, благодарю! Думаю, разберусь...